# MVVM light and Navigation "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have set up my `ViewModelLocator` like so:

```
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => this.CreateNavigationService());
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDialogService, DialogService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUnitOfWork, InfiniUnitOfWork>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<TrendingGagsViewModel>();

    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public TrendingGagsViewModel TrendingGags
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<TrendingGagsViewModel>();
        }
    }


    private INavigationService CreateNavigationService()
    {
        var navigationService = new NavigationService();
        navigationService.Configure("TrendingGag", typeof(TrendingGagsViewModel));
        return navigationService;
    }
```

I have my `MainPage` and my `TrendingGagPage` set up like so:

```
<Page
    x:Class="_Blah.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:_Blah"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}"
    Name="Page"
    Background="Black">
...

<Page x:Class="_Blah.TrendingGagsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:_Blah"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=TrendingGags}"
    Background="Black">
...
```

My `MainViewModel` injects the `INavigationService` like so:

```
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    INavigationService navigationService;

    public MainViewModel(IUnitOfWork uow, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = uow;
        this.navigationService = navigationService;
    }
```

and has a property like so:

```
    public RelayCommand<Page> ButtonCommand_LoadGagPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<Page>(page => navigationService.NavigateTo("TrendingGag", page));
        }
    }
```

When i click a button on my `MainNavigation` page... It goes through to the `RelayCommand`... and then throws the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

`this.navigationService` shows an object present?

What might be going wrong??

My stack trace looks like this:

```
   at _Blah._Gag_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType, Object parameter)
   at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Views.NavigationService.NavigateTo(String pageKey, Object parameter)
   at _Blah.ViewModels.MainViewModel.<get_ButtonCommand_LoadGagPage>b__6_0(Page page)
```

Comment: where is "TrendingGag" defined?

Comment: I thought the string defined a key which attached to the type of class it's assigned to: `navigationService.Configure("TrendingGag", typeof(TrendingGagsViewModel));` and then you can call to navigate to that class by that key you assigned: `navigationService.NavigateTo("TrendingGag", page)`

Comment: It should be th epage & not the VM : navigationService.Configure("TrendingGag", typeof(TrendingGagsPage))

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh! I'll try when i get home. Thanks man!

Comment: @Nikita - that's the answer! Thanks man!